# Integration of $\frac{1}{x}\,\tan^{-1} \frac{1}{x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to find
$$
\int \frac{1}{x}\, \tan^{-1} \frac{1}{x} \, dx.
$$

I have tried using product rule, by taking $\frac{1}{x}$ as 1st function and $\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{x}$ as second function, but the integration does not end. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: I tried on paper but didn't get anywhere. I put this into [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+1%2Fx+arctan+%281%2Fx%29+dx) and it output something in terms of dilogarithms. It may not be possible to do in terms of more elementary functions.

Comment: After making the initial substitution $\frac{1}{x}=t$, you are left with the [inverse tangent integral function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseTangentIntegral.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$I=\int\frac{1}{x}\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\,dx=-\int \frac{1}{t}\tan ^{-1}\left(t\right)\,dt$$ Integration by parts
$$I=-\log (t) \tan ^{-1}(t)+\int\frac{\log (t)}{t^2+1}\,dt$$
$$J=\int\frac{\log (t)}{t^2+1}\,dt=\int\frac{\log (t)}{(t+i)(t-i)}\,dt=\frac i 2\int \left(\frac{\log (t)}{t+i}-\frac{\log (t)}{t-i} \right)\,dt$$ Simple change of variable
$$\int \frac{\log (t)}{t+a} \,dt=\text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{t}{a}\right)+\log (t) \log
   \left(1+\frac{t}{a}\right)$$ and then the result given by Wolfram Alpha
$$I=\frac{1}{2} i
   \left(\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{i}{x}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(-\frac
   {i}{x}\right)\right)$$

**Edit**

If we use the series expansion of $\tan ^{-1}\left(t\right)$, we have
$$I=\int \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \frac{t^{2 n}}{2 n+1}\,dt= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \frac{t^{2 n+1}}{(2 n+1)^2}=
-\frac{t}{4} \,\Phi \left(-t^2,2,\frac{1}{2}\right)$$ where appears [the Lerch transcendent function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html)